# Updating a Big State Fast in Haskell

Tags: data-structures, haskell, state-monad

For my vector graphics library in Haskell I must carry around a rather big state: line stroke parameters, colors, clip path etc. I know two ways of doing this. Quoting a comment from [Haskell-cafe](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg71839.html): "I would suggest you either use a reader monad with mutable state, or a state monad with immutable state".

Here is my problem: updating a big immutable state is a performance kill. Using lots of STRefs is like writing C in Haskell: it's verbose and ugly.

Here is the immutable state:

```
data GfxState = GfxState {
  lineWidth :: Double,
  lineCap :: Int,
  color :: Color,
  clip :: Path,
  ...
}

setLineWidth :: Double -> State GfxState ()
setLineWidth x = modify (\state -> state { lineWidth = x })
```

As far as I know, "state { lineWidth = x }" creates a new GfxState and lets the old one be garbage collected. This kills performance when the state is big and updated often.

Here is the mutable state:

```
data GfxState s = GfxState {
  lineWidth :: STRef s Double,
  lineCap   :: STRef s Int,
  color     :: STRef s Color,
  clip      :: STRef s Path,
  ...
  many more STRefs
}

setLineWidth :: GfxState s -> Double -> ST s ()
setLineWidth state x = writeSTRef (lineWidth state) x
```

Now I get (GfxState s) and (ST s) and (STRef s) all over the place, which is verbose, confusing, and beats the spirit of writing short and expressive code. I could use C + FFI to read and update the big state, but since I encounter this pattern quite often, I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: Doing what you're doing is going to be like writing C in haskell, because the library interface I see you hinting at is a very imperative interface.  `setLineWidth`?  Making the interface in a more functional style will make the implementation more functional as well.

Comment: For the first version, updating the state with "state { lineWidth = x }" should have sharing with the old state so I wouldn't expect it to  create a whole new state. You might want to make at least "atomic" elements of the state strict (e.g. lineWidth becomes !Double and lineCap becomes !Int), I suspect this could be hampering performance quite a bit.

Comment: @stephen, well the *values* are shared with the old record.  But if you have a record with 100 fields, every record update will copy 100 pointers.

Comment: @luqui - Indeed, but that strongly suggests "Don't make a record with 100 fields then..." and adding some nesting to group associated elements together. This would be more modular and better from a comprehensibility point of view, anyway.

Comment: @luqui, setLineWidth doesn't belong to the interface. The interface has a function that takes a list of commands (moveTo, lineTo, setColor, setLineWidth, stroke etc.) and produces a list of graphics objects (Stroke {path::Path, color::Color etc.}).

Comment: @DJS, you just said that "setLineWidth" is one of the commands it can take.  That's what I meant.  If that is the problem you are solving -- say taking a list of commands on standard input and drawing them, then cool.  But if you are writing more haskell that will use this, then a list of commands is not what I would recommend as an interface.  A combinator library will be nicer to work with.  See http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/graphics-drawingcombinators/0.3/doc/html/Graphics-DrawingCombinators.html for inspiration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even with quite a few fields in your record, "creating a new one" just means copying pointers. And "letting the old one be garbage collected" just means releasing a few bytes for each pointer in a way that GHC's generational garbage collector is very fast at handling. It all boils down to a handful of machine instructions. So even for a graphics application, that very well may not kill your performance at all.

If you are sure that it really does impact on performance, organize the fields into a tree. You can create a fixed-shape tree by using nested `data` types, or even just use `Data.IntMap`. That will get you an average of `log n / 2` pointer copies. You can do even better if you know that certain fields are accessed much more often.

It would be a very rare application whose state is so complex and whose performance requirements are so heavy that the only option is `STRef` fields. But it's nice to know that the option is there.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I'll do. Stick to the immutable state (i.e. no ST monad), and move the fields to a tree form later during performance optimization. I'm a bit disappointed because this is the first time since switching to Haskell that I actually miss C.

Answer (score 10):

First of all I have to ask are you just claiming it's going to be slow or did you profile or at least notice a performance issue? otherwise guessing or making assumptions isn't particuarly useful. Anyway I recommend grouping your data, at the moment it looks like you're just laying out your structure completely flat when you could group related data like the data related to lines into records.

You might also want to seperate out bits that really need to be in the state monad and others that don't into a reader/writer monad and combine them using monad transformers. Regarding elegance of code I'd recommend using (first-class/higher-order) record libraries like fclabels.

I've made heavy use of state monads (in a stack of a monad transformer) in a few small projects and I haven't noticed any performance issues yet.

Lastly you could use modify instead of a get/put pairs.

Comment: Thanks. The fclabels library looks interesting.

Comment: I changed the sample code to use "modify" instead of "get" and "put". Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As an aside, you should certainly be improving your data type representation via unboxing, if you are concerned about performance:

```
data GfxState = GfxState {
  lineWidth :: {-# UNPACK #-}!Double,
  lineCap   :: {-# UNPACK #-}!Int,
  color     :: {-# UNPACK #-}!Color,
  clip      :: Path,
  ...
}
```

By unpacking the constructors, you improve the density of your data, going from a heap structure like this:

[image]

to the denser, stricter:

[image]

Now all the atomic types are laid out in consecutive memory slots. Updating this type will be much faster! *BTW, 461.. is the Word representation of the pi field, a bug in my viewer library*

You'll also reduce the chance of space leaks.

The cost of passing such a structure around will be very cheap, as the components will be stored in registers.